# How to use Wget to download correct image size with extension ".jpg?size=2000"

Tags: wget, imagedownload

I need to download many images, some have extensions like this:
http://example.com/image.jpeg**?size=2000**

In the browser I see a large image, but wget only downloads the smaller version of this image (without the "?size=2000" part).
Any idea how to download the large images from the terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try enclosing the url in quotes?

Comment: @baf yes it gives the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm listing some sample codes so we have a basis for discussion.

Do any of these work?

```
curl -O 'http://example.com/image.jpeg?size=2000'
wget 'http://example.com/image.jpeg?size=2000'
wget 'http://example.com/image.jpeg?size=2000&ran=abcd123'
wget -O image.jpeg 'http://example.com/image.jpeg?size=2000'
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok so jpeg is just a file extension. open the image go to file> Save as> advanced options> choose file extension that's how.
Advanced setting may not be there, its how it is on mac it should be the same.
if not it should just display it!
hope this helps. :)

Comment: I can't do that, I have thousands of files to download, I need something more automated